Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Show that the tangent bundle $TM$ is always an orientable manifold (my own proof).
This question is from a publicly available old qualifying exam (Stanford geometry and topology), which I am using to help learn this field. I have seen no proof for this problem anywhere; all work is my own.


Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Show that the tangent bundle $TM$ is always an orientable manifold.

Answer: The strategy is to construct an orientation on the tangent bundle. The methods used closely follow information in Lee's chapter on orientations, in particular pages 378 and 379.
Have the dimension of $M$ be $k$. The tangent bundle is as a set the disjoint union of all tangent spaces on the manifold, which are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^k$. We already know that each tangent space has an orientation.
We can easily construct the orientation as such.  Have $E_{pq} : T_p M \rightarrow T_q M $ be the transition matrix that takes the choice of basis on $T_p M$ to the choice of basis on $T_q M$.
Let $O_q$ be the current orientation on $T_q M$. Then define a new orientation $O'q$ on $T_q M $ by the following
$O_q' = \begin{cases} O_q & \text{if } \det(E_{pq}) > 0 \\ - O_q & \text{if }  \det(E_{pq}) < 0  \end {cases}$.
Computing $O'q$ for each point $q$ gives a consistent orientation across all tangent spaces. The tangent bundle is the disjoint union of all tangent spaces glued together by some topology. Since all tangent spaces have the same orientation, any arbitrary neighborhood or intersection of neighborhoods of the tangent bundle will have the same orientation. Thus $TM$ has a globally constructible orientation.

(a) Is this explicit construction OK? IE, can I do this direct approach and avoid, say, anything regarding transition functions, orientation forms, covering spaces, or fancier tools of the like?
As a bonus, if anyone has any approach that they find cleaner, more efficient, (or correct if mine isn't), then feel free to let me know. Thanks in advance.
